# Cannot resolve symbol 'onRadioButtonClicked'

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Android: onClick = "onRadioButtonClicked" has the same name as the function. I can not understand why he does not recognize it.
The poblem is in xml file, " Cannot resolve symbol 'onRadioButtonClicked' " on the `Android: onClick = "onRadioButtonClicked"` line

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton)

My xml file

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupLag"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/radioButtonEnglish">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_lang"
                android:text="@string/txt_language"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonGreek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/RadioButtonGreek"
            android:onClick= "onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonEnglish"
            android:text="@string/RadioButtonEnglish"
            android:onClick= "onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonGerman"
                android:text="@string/RadioButtonGerman"
                android:onClick= "onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        </RadioGroup>
```

My fun in the Fragment:

```
private fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is RadioButton) {
           
            val checked = view.isChecked
          
            // Check which radio button was clicked
            when (view.getId()) {

               R.id.radioButtonGreek->{
                   if (checked) {
                        changeLag()
                    }
               
               }
                R.id.radioButtonGerman ->{ 
                    if (checked) {
                        changeLag()
                    }
                }
                R.id.radioButtonEnglish-> {
                    if (checked) {
                        changeLag()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

End i call the fun in onCreateView

```
  onRadioButtonClicked(binding.radioGroupLag)
```

Comment: Try removing private from before the function

Comment: I have turned it into public but it still does not work.

Comment: Try removing the space behind the name in OnClick

Answer (score 1):

> The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>
> - **Be public**
> - Return void
> - Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

Quote from [the guide you linked](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) (emphasis mine). Make your method public.

Comment: I have turned it into public but it still does not work.